# Protein phosphorylation in the cytoplasm. Typical time scale?

Tags: biophysics, phosphorylation

Is there a typical protein phosphorylation rate in the cell cytoplasm under physiological conditions, or at least an upper-bound?

Suppose a protein $A$ is being phosphorylated into $A^*$ with the first order reaction

$A \to ^k A^*$

where $k$ is the reaction rate ($k$ unit is $\rm time^{-1}$).

In reality a phosphorylation reaction involves multiple agents (protein, enzyme, ATP) and multiple reactions, therefore cannot be accurately mapped onto a first order reaction. However this makes sense if we are only interested in the order of magnitude of $k$. According to this first order reaction the evolution of the $A$ concentration is given by
$$
\frac{d A}{dt}=-k A
$$
and therefore $1/k$ is the time scale at which $A$ vary.

So my question can also be formulated as: suppose that at a given time a cytoplasmic protein $A$ starts to be phosphorylated into $A^*$. What is the typical time scale at which the concentrations of $A$ and $A^*$ reach their equilibrium values?

From few things I read it looks like it is of the order of seconds or minutes or hours, and 1 second seems to be an upper bound. Any references?

Comment: Phosphorylation is not a first order reaction, it always Protein + ATP -(enzyme)-> Protein-P + ADP  (in rare cases a different Phosphate carrier might be used as well). While the concentration of ATP is somewhat kept stable, you shouldn't/can't assume it doesn't matter.
Otherwise I'm not sure, the [Brenda](http://www.brenda-enzymes.org) database might have some numbers for Kinases, but getting 'average' or upper/lower bounds might be tricky

Comment: Sure it is not a first order reaction, but to some extend you can always look how fast the concentration of the unphosphorylated protein (A) changes with time and get the coefficient $k$ which will be your "effective first order rate", that will be function of ATP, enzymes, etc. That is just to get roughly an order of magnitude.

Comment: @Nicolai I just edited the question, I hope it makes more sense in this way.

Comment: yeah, I think with the edits it's much clearer why you would assume a first order reaction in this case. Did you take a look at the [Brenda database](http://www.brenda-enzymes.org) for some kinases (phosphorylation enzymes) and possible reaction values? I'd also assume that depending on the kinase (not so much the target), the order of magnitude for k might be very different.